# How to simplify this simple assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make this clearer and more concise?

```
def right_menu_link(name, url, css_class = nil)
  css_class += " arrow" if css_class
  css_class = "arrow" unless css_class
  # ... rest of code
end
```

I've come up with at least this:

```
def right_menu_link(name, url, css_class = nil)
  css_class ||= []; css_class << " arrow"
  # ... rest of code
end
```

Comment: The first code expect/returns a String for css_class, the 2nd coding an array. What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
css_class = css_class ? "arrow" : css_class + " arrow"
```

It's known as [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator

```
css_class = css_class ? " arrow" : css_class + " arrow"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def right_menu_link(name, url, css_class = nil)
  css_class = [*css_class] << ' arrow'
end
```

Always good to know your [splats](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/22/rubys-splat-operator/).
Also, you're avoiding a conditional, compared to using a ternary operator.

EDIT As was pointed out, ruby versions < 1.9 leave the nil in the array. Newer versions ignore the nil, as was intended in the example.

Comment: when `css_class` is `nil`, this returns `[nil, " arrow"]`, which is not expected

Comment: @apneadiving I tested this with ruby 1.9.3 and there was no nil in the array when css_class = nil. EDIT: Just checked ruby < 1.9 does keep the nil.

Comment: I know :) your line is not valid for 1.8.7 and ree

Answer (score 0):

I know its not so cool, since it will work only in valid cases, i.e. on missing argument or on array provided.

```
def right_menu_link(name, url, css_class = [])
  css_class << ' arrow'
end
```